# Why has my Android become half-rooted?

Tags: root-access, superuser

I had rooted my Samsung Galaxy S 4G, and for some reason it seems to be only partially rooted now. What I mean by this is that while SuperUser is installed, apps such as BusyBox and Titanium Backup are complaining that they cannot get root access. Using apps from the Google Play store, I can neither remove the root or re-root the device. I cannot get to the Recovery menu because the key combinations done at startup just end up rebooting my device. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Resetting the phone to factory settings does nothing.

Despite all this, AVG Antivirus is complaining that my device is rooted. So, what's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember encountering a similar problem with superuser. I installed [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) from Google Play (replacing the superuser app), and it fixed my problems.

**Update #1:** As discussed over chat, jeffreylin_'s root was lost, as verified with Root Checker. To fix this, the phone must be rooted again. [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) can be used; no need to flash ROM or anything. Just run the tool. It supports Samsung Galaxy S 4G.

**Edit #2:** In case you want to protect root (after phone's been rooted), install [OTA Rootkeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper), so you can just restore root if you mess it up.

Comment: But Super User came installed with my ROM...

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Superuser is different from SuperSU. Look for SuperSU in Google Play. I posted the link in my answer.

Comment: I pressed all the buttons, none of them work. It also seems that my SU binary is outdated.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: It tells me that the SU binary is missing, and when I press the normal button, it says installation failed and exits. If I hit TWRP, it doesn't transfer me there, but instead let's me into the app. None of the settings do anything, such as 'install SuperUser into /system' and 'full unroot'

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Can you go to the chatroom?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have su installed (the program that allows you to become root) but it may lack the right permissions to run. In this scenario, AVG is probably just checking if su is installed but apps that need root fail to run. You might be able to change the file permission using adb and chmod (I don't know the exact command but may be easy to google for it).

Answer (score 0):

you could use chown command to give su its rights.

Comment: While this *might* help: How should Jeff accomplish that? Could you please [edit] your answer and include at least a short step-by-step instruction?

Answer (score 0):

In my case replacing SuperSU from the Play store did not fix the problem.

What *did* fix the problem was copying *su* from */su/bin* to */system/xbin*.